# Is it possible for the format of a cell to execute a formula on the cell contents?

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking to format a cell in such a way that the cell displays a modified version of the contents of the cell. Specifically, I am looking to insert a date in a cell, and then modify the date by adding 60 days to it.

Currently, I am using two cells:

A1 is where I input the date "2020/05/26"

B1 returns the value that I am actually interested in "=A1+60"

I have formatted A1 to hide the text, but ideally I would like to have *one* cell in which I can input the current date, and have this date modified by adding 60 days.

Is it possible to format the cell to display the desired (modified) date?

Comment: 2 possible approaches... ***1*** have Excel automatically bump the date after you enter it.... ***2*** Make Excel lie and display the date 60 days in advance ............ which do you prefer ??

Comment: It would be helpful to have a more descriptive title, also tags so a user looking for certain types of questions will find this, without thinking about it I do not know to what this question pertains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Event macro monitors your changes to **A1**.  It will add 60 to whatever value you type in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")

    If Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With A1
        If .Value = 0 Then Exit Sub
        If .Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Not IsNumeric(.Value2) Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Value = .Value + 60
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

If you:

1. clear **A1**
2. put 0 in **A1**
3. put text in **A1**

then no action is taken.

Action is only taken for dates and numbers.
Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**